# url could not parse data json

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, branch.io

using branch.io i am developed differed deep linking for cordova application.the url generated by the branch dynamic builder not redirect to playstore in android it shows the erreo message in browser like:{could not parse data json} 
My link is:https://bnc.lt/a/key_live_hhoW7g0luMxwlGYKg4TelepbrzdSrV36?&param=directories.html?id=CqM6gcSK53&data=eyIkYWx3YXlzX2RlZXBsaW5rIjoiVHJ1ZSJ9==

Comment: its not showing any error message but forwarding to http://egsd.mobldir.com:8080/egsdMobileApp/home.html

Answer (score 1):

Wrong:
https://bnc.lt/a/key_live_hhoW7g0luMxwlGYKg4TelepbrzdSrV36?&param=directories.html?id=CqM6gcSK53&data=eyIkYWx3YXlzX2RlZXBsaW5rIjoiVHJ1ZSJ9==

Correct:
https://bnc.lt/a/key_live_hhoW7g0luMxwlGYKg4TelepbrzdSrV36?param=directories.html&id=CqM6gcSK53&data=eyIkYWx3YXlzX2RlZXBsaW5rIjoiVHJ1ZSJ9==

Misplaced "&" and "=" signs.

Comment: Alex from Branch.io: this looks correct to me. Also check out the documentation [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links-other-ways/guide/#appending-query-parameters) for more info on how to structure these links.